# open window on click of button as modal dialog using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have to open a window when a button is clicked, as a modal dialog using JavaScript.
I have used `window.open`, but it shows me two instances, the parent page and the pop-up page.
When the pop-up page is open, then do not allow the user to click on the parent page.

```
function openWindow() {
  var w = 950;
  var h = 350;
  var t = 0;
  var l = 0;
  var scrollbars = 1;
  var modal = 'yes';

  var reportWindow = window.open("Search.aspx" + '', '', "width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",left=" + l + ",top=" + t + ',scrollbars=' + scrollbars + 'modal' + modal);
  reportWindow.focus();
}
```

Comment: see this may be helpful to you http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/index.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code line,

```
reportWindow = window.open("Search.aspx" + '', '', "width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",left=" + l + ",top=" + t + ',scrollbars=' + scrollbars + 'modal' + modal);
```

is missing an '=' symbol after modal. It should be,

```
reportWindow = window.open("Search.aspx" + '', '', "width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",left=" + l + ",top=" + t + ',scrollbars=' + scrollbars + 'modal=' + modal);
```

To open window as dialog box,

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function openWindow() {
       if (window.showModalDialog) {
window.showModalDialog("http://example.com","name",
"dialogWidth:255px;dialogHeight:250px");
} else {
window.open('http://example.com','name',
'height=255,width=250,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no, linemenubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no ,modal=yes');
}
    } 
    </script>
    <button onclick="openWindow();">Open window</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If the above code is not working, please use jQuery modal dialog. You can load any urls to dialog using an iframe.

Comment: read the question again. `but it shows me two instances parent page as well as pop up page. when popup page is open then donot allow to click on parent page.`

Comment: user970349  :: See Title of quetion i already ask  MODAL DIALOG IN JAVASCRIPT

Comment: user window.showmodaldialog also does not work as modal dialog box i checked it.

Comment: window.showmodaldialog will not work in all browsers. please check updated answer

Comment: @john Please check your code 'reportWindow = window.open("Search.aspx" + '', '', "width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",left=" + l + ",top=" + t + ',scrollbars=' + scrollbars + 'modal' + modal);
             reportWindow = window.open("Search.aspx" + '', '', "width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",left=" + l + ",top=" + t + ',scrollbars=' + scrollbars + 'modal' + modal);  The modal is missing an '=' symbol.

Comment: Try the above code. If it also not working try jQuery modal dialog.

Comment: According to developer.mozilla.org the showModayDialog is now deprecated: [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog)

Answer (score 2):

"window.open" will not work. This command always just opens a popup wich is not "always" on top of its parent.

2 Options:

1. If you just want to let the user enter a search string you could use

   ```
   prompt("Please enter a search string:", "");
   ```
2. If you have a complexe search form, you have to create a modal dialog for your own.
   There are frameworks which provide this functionality (google for "jQuery") or you create it for your own. Should not be hard, tell me if you need some help!

Comment: PLEADE READ MY QUETION ATLEAST ONCE I HAVE TO OPEN MODAL POPUP AS PAGE  ON BUTTON CLICK

Comment: I did and as I told you, it is not possible to use window.open to do this secure and make it working in all browsers. You have to generate the modal windown in javascript using jQuery or something written by our own.